# C# Open Google Search With Search Request

Tags: c#, string

I have an InputTextbox that will have text in it such as:

"search google for test"

And this is the code I have at the moment:

```
String searchRequest = InputTextbox.Text;
searchRequest = searchRequest.SubString(searchRequest.IndexOf("for ") + 4, searchRequest.Length-1);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + searchRequest);
```

What I am trying to do is search the "InputTextbox.Text" for the word "for" and use anything after it as the search term.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this please.

Comment: I'd get rid of the hard coded reference to internet explorer. Let windows figure out what browser the user wants to use and just pass the url instead.

Comment: Also, what goes wrong? Do you get an error? Does a browser open and go to the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry - the error returned is "StartIndex cannot be less than zero"

Comment: An alternative would be to use Selenium, but that may be over-kill in your case, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @TheWoo: you are giving length of the string as second parameter , you should pass the length of the string tobe extracted out of it, check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One error is in the SubString. The second parameter is meant to be the length of the substring, not the index of the end of the substring. You need to change this to:

```
searchRequest.SubString(searchRequest.IndexOf("for ") + 4, searchRequest.Length-1 - (searchRequest.IndexOf("for ") + 4));
```

If that makes sense.

I would avoid using substring here anyway because it can be quite unpredictable. For example, if "for" is not typed into the textbox, you'll get an error and if two "for"s are typed in, I don't even know what will happen. You should try usin RegExp (http://www.regular-expressions.info/) instead:

```
        String searchRequest = InputTextbox.Text;
        searchRequest = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<=for ?).+$").Match(searchRequest).Value;

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + System.Uri.EscapeDataString(searchRequest));
```

Note that I have removed the "iexplore" bit from the process.start routine. This is ok for people who use internet explorer, but it is best not to specify a browser here so as the default browser can be used instead. Note also that I have used System.Uri.EscapeDataString. This will cover you incase the user enters an ampersand into the search box.

Answer (score 0):

If the error says `"StartIndex cannot be less than zero"` then there will be probably something wrong here:

```
searchRequest.Length-1
```

For example, searchRequest.Length may be zero and you're subtracting 1 from it.

Comment: Op is trying with String `search google for test` so it can not be 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**  you are giving complete `String Length` as second parameter for `Substring()` function.
**Solution :** You should provide the substring `Length` (number of characters to be `extracted` out of the string) as second `Parameter` for `Substring()`
 function.

Syntax of `Substring()` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Substring(Int32, Int32)  :    Retrieves a substring from this instance.
>   The substring starts at a specified character position and has a
>   specified **length**.

Try This:

```
String searchRequest = "search google for test";
int index = searchRequest.IndexOf("for ") + 4;
searchRequest = searchRequest.Substring(index,searchRequest.Length-index);

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "http://www.google.com.au/search?q=" + searchRequest);
```